# Reference-Less .NET ORM for Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, orm

I was wondering if anyone knew of an ORM for .NET that is compatible with Oracle.

Here's the catch, I would like to not have to add a reference to any third party libraries in my data abstraction layer.

I've used Telerik's OpenAccess ORM and it works great; except I have to add a reference to Telerik's DLLs in my project.

Since I am calling just stored procedures from Oracle I do not need the enhanced LINQ functionality that comes with modern (albeit heavy) ORMs.

I am more or less looking for a code generator that will examine Oracle and allow me to select what packages/procedures I'd like to use, then generate methods using preferably Oracle.DataAccess.Client to call the procedures.

I am currently creating these methods manually but it's becoming more and more of a pain to keep track of variable names and package names.

Does anyone know of anything that might help?

Thanks!

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Comment: Why can't you add a reference? Are you trying to make this much harder than it needs to be?

Comment: Because real world applications shouldn't have assembly references that we have no control over. I want to generate access methods and then have the ability to change the source if needed. It really isn't that difficult to code something up in PL/SQL to generate the package access code, however, I was asking if something already existed. Also, adding references to ORM tools slows down performance  because all code/mappings happen inside it and then are ultimately sent to Oracle.DataAccess.Client. I want to eliminate the middle man.

Comment: Not sure where you got that impression -- real world applications tend to have lots of references one has no control over, starting with the .NET BCL. As for performance, I'd bet on the guys writing the good ORMs over my skills in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to add reference, use reflection and load assembly dynamically and invoke methods and pass parameters to it. It will be more PITA and code will be hard to read, manage or debug

Comment: I am not sure that your answer addresses my question. I can't use reflection against an external Oracle Database. I was talking about a tool to generate access procs by querying Oracle's user_arguments view.